# Does Improved Pact Weapon include ammo?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations, ammunition

The Warlock Invocation "Improved Pact Weapon" from Xanathar's Guide allows the warlock to summon a ranged weapon:

> Finally, the weapon you conjure can be a shortbow, longbow, light crossbow, or heavy crossbow.

Does this include the associated ammunition (arrows or bolts)?  Or will the warlock have to carry ammo to use when he summons his bow/crossbow?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since it does not say that it includes ammunition, it doesn't include ammunition. If an ability says that a special item does not require ammunition, it says so, such as with the Artificer Infusion "Repeating Shot" which includes the line

> If you load no ammunition in the weapon, it produces its own...

Since the eldritch invocation does not include a similar line, it could seem that no, if you summon a weapon that requires ammunition, the invocation does not provide it

This is further supported by a [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/929426951109873664) tweet where upon being asked this same question, he responds

> No ranged weapon automatically generates its own ammunition unless its description or a special ability says otherwise.

Comment: This is the answer I expected, but wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something.  Thanks!